# are there some libraries like java httpclient in ruby

Tags: java, ruby, http, httpclient

i want to know whether there are libraries like java httpclient in ruby?
great thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Net::HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/) if you don't want an external dependency, [Curb](http://curb.rubyforge.org/)/[Curl::Multi](http://curl-multi.rubyforge.org/) if you need raw performance, [Patron](http://patron.rubyforge.org/) if you want a good middle-of-the-road solution, and [open-uri](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) if you need something quick and dirty that will never see production usage.

Patron is usually my favored solution.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby comes with the [Net/HTTP](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html) library out of the box. I recommend using that first, and if you need something higher level, look at external libraries like e.g. REST client.

Answer (score 0):

[REST Client](http://github.com/adamwiggins/rest-client) is pretty handy and easy to use library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either of these two?

[ruby-httpclient](http://code.google.com/p/ruby-httpclient/)
[Patron](http://patron.rubyforge.org/)